# Do we still need Class (or KClass) after having Reified?

Tags: kotlin

With `reified`, I could replace the below function

```
private fun <T>createFragmentX(fragmentClass: Class<T>, fragmentArgs: Bundle?): Fragment {
    try {
        val fragment = fragmentClass.newInstance() as Fragment
        fragment.arguments = fragmentArgs
        return fragment
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        throw RuntimeException(exception.message)
    }
}
```

with this

```
private inline fun <reified T>createFragmentZ(fragmentArgs: Bundle?): Fragment {
    try {
        val fragment = T::class.java.newInstance() as Fragment
        fragment.arguments = fragmentArgs
        return fragment
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        throw RuntimeException(exception.message)
    }
}
```

It looks to me, with `reified` there's no longer need of using `Class` or `KClass`. Am I right?

Is there other use of `Class` or `KClass` that can't be fulfilled by `reified`, other than wanted to do pure reflection work?

Comment: Why not `private inline fun <reified T: Fragment>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer:

In your example, it does not make a difference, except for aesthetics.

### Long answer:

If you pass in `T` as `reified`, you can retrieve the `KClass` from the `reified` type parameter `T` like this

```
val kClass = T::class
```

at any time. You then have all the options you would have using a `KClass` as parameter, so no difference here.

---

There are situations where you need to use `KClass` as parameter though. Here a two:

**1) No inline**

When you don't want your function to be `inline`, because using a `reified` type works only with inlined functions.

**2) Default values**

Another situation would be default values:

```
fun f(kClass: KClass<*> = Int::class) { /*...*/ }
```

You couldn't achieve exactly the same with a reified type parameter.

**Conclusion:**

In all other cases go for the generic type parameter, because it makes the call-site more concise as shown here (which may be personal preference):

```
inline fun <reified T> printType() {
    println(T::class.simpleName)
}

fun printType(kClass: KClass<*>) {
    println(kClass.simpleName)
}
```

Call-site

```
printType<Int>() // better
printType(Int::class)
```

Comment: 3) when it's a _class_ parameter (though you can make a helper function with `reified`).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass it as a *parameter* here, but your code still uses `Class`: that's what `T::class.java` is. So yes, there are many cases where you need `Class` and yours is one of them.